# Short film about a time loop?

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I remember watching a short film years ago about a time loop where there's this guy in a white plastic onesie with goggles, almost like a CSI worker. It starts with him in a room behind a chair I think and it ends with him jumping off a building onto a safety mat. He tries to avoid other people throughout and it turns out the other people are him in other loops.

Comment: This is a good overall description, can you remember anything else about it though? For example, roughly how long ago did you watch it? Can you remember how long it was? Was it live action, cartoon, anime, etc.? As you've already looked for it, was there anything similar you found that you can discount? If you want to add any other details to the question or you remember something else to add please [edit] it into your post. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Does https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235668/60s-70s-movie-with-buggies-and-time-shifting-protagonist look familiar?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are referring to ["Mouse X"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3575442/), a sci-fi short movie by Justin Tagg, created in 2014 and available on YouTube:

All of your described details fit (white suit with goggles, trying not to be seen, jumping onto a mattress). He does not start out behind the chair, but waking up on an armchair, but a later scene reveals that another version of him is, at that moment, hiding behind that very armchair.

I am just not sure whether the person is in a time loop, or whether there are actually many copies (clones?) of him in a carefully arranged environment that lets all of them always make the same choices over and over.